# 'non-intrusive' translation with c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, translation

`gettext`, `poedit`, etc. are standard tools usually used for translation (eg. to "spanish") of user facing texts, etc.

Intrusive here refers to that the source code is intruded with translation functions.

This can be a huge work load to install the correct translation calls manually for an existing code base (it's usually not just search+replace every string since there will usually be a lot of strings that's undesirable to get translated).

So, if the UI is made up of native controls only, would it be possible to switch the strings at runtime (at or just after creation ideally) ?

Comment: "_So, if the UI is made up of native controls only, would it be possible to switch the strings at runtime (at or just after creation ideally) ?_" Yes. Language packs, work in the similar way.

Comment: *"Intrusive here refers to that the source code is intruded with translation functions."* What do you mean here? `std::cout << gettext("Hello world")` seems the minimal. Not all C-String literal requires translations.

Comment: In Windows, the UI consists of separate data files.  You create a different copy of these data files for each language. If you plan for internationalization from the start, then it's non-intrusive. It sure is a lot less work if you stick to keeping all printable text in these data files at all times.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Thats a good point, our issue is that only a subset of the strings are kept in the resource file. Alot of dialogs  and stuff are just using `L""` directly in code

Comment: That's what I feared.  "It sure is a lot less work if..."